# Orchard Autofac throws not assignable exception

Tags: c#, autofac, orchardcms

I have the following service:

```
public Interface IService<T> : IDependency {
      T Execute();
}
```

and:

```
   public class Service<T> : IService<T> Where T : class, new() {
          T Execute();
   }
```

Orchard Crashes and throws the following exception:

> The type 'Service`1[T]' is not assignable to service 'IService`1'.

any help is much appreciated.

Comment: show registration code also.

Comment: @tchelidze Orchard Automatically register any service that implement`IDependency` .

Comment: @mjwills at startup

Comment: Error is quite clear. You can't have `Service<T>` without specifying `T`. So it tries to register `Service<T>` as instantiable object, which it isn't. I think you should disable auto registration for `Service<T>` and register all concretes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you really need T to be on the service anyway? Just do:

```
public interface IService : IDependency {
  T Execute<T>();
}
```

Then you get the benefits of Orchard's automatic dependency injection